# How to rely on CLT without standardizing coefficients?

Tags: inference, interpretation, standardization, central-limit-theorem

How can a person rely on Central Limit Theorem if he/she does not want to standardize coefficients in order to stick to the original interpretation?
If I cannot rely on CLT then my inference results are unreliable. So do I have to choose between keeping the original interpretation and the reliability of the inference, or am I missing something?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "rely on the CLT."  Its applicability has nothing to do with whether or not you standardize anything.

Comment: From Introductory Econometrics (Wooldridge) I read "regardless of the population distribution of u, the OLS estimators, when properly standardized, have approximate standard normal distributions."
From this sentence I would expect that unstandardized OLS do not have an approximate normal distribution, then I cannot rely on

Comment: Also I read: 
"the theorem says that, regardless of the population distribution of u, the OLS estimators, when properly standardized, have approximate standard normal distributions."

I'm getting confused by the above two.

Comment: "... when properly standardized, have approximate standard normal distributions" suggests that "..." before being standardized had an approximate normal distribution without having to have a mean of $0$ or variance of $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual Central Limit Theorem is as follows. Let $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ be an IID sample with $E(Y_i)=\mu,\text{var}(Y_i)=\sigma^2$ for all $i$, where both $\mu,\sigma^2$ are finite. Furthermore, let $\bar Y$ be the sample average. Then

$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar Y-\mu)}{\sigma}\overset{d}{\to}N(0,1),
$$

where $\overset{d}{\to}$ means convergence in distribution.

Now, in the limit, or when $n$ is sufficiently large, we can replace $\overset{d}{\to}$ by $\sim$.

Thus, in the limit or for large $n$, using properties of the normal distribution we have

$$
\bar Y \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2/n).
$$

To be more precise, only in the limit we have exact equality in distribution (at least, at all the continuity points of the distribution of the sequence) whereas for large $n$ we only have an approximate equality.

In your case, let $\hat \beta$ the the OLS estimator and $\hat{\text{var}}(\hat\beta)$ the estimated variance. Then by the same token,

$$
\frac{\hat\beta-\beta}{\sqrt{\hat{\text{var}}(\hat\beta)}}\overset{d}{\to} N(0,1),
$$

thus for large sample sizes

$$
\hat\beta\sim N(\beta, \hat{\text{var}}(\hat\beta)).
$$

So the normal limiting distribution holds also in the nonstandardized case, again, exactly in the limit and only approximately for large $n$.

Comment: $\bar Y \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2/n) \text{ as } n\to\infty$ is a slight abuse of notation with $\sim$ meaning either "distributed as" or "approximately" and probably intended to be a mixture of the two.   $N(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$ cannot be the limiting distribution as $n\to\infty$ since it mentions $n$, while $N(\mu, 0)$ as the limit might be read as the law of large numbers rather than the central limit theorem.  So instead the handwaving argument is that for "big enough" $n$ you will eventually have  $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar Y-\mu)}{\sigma}$ approximately distributed $N(0,1)$ and then destandardise

Comment: @Henry you are right thanks you! I’ve updated my answer to highlight that issue.

Answer (score 4):

You require standardizing (in a particular fashion, not necessarily to standard normal) for the CLT itself, otherwise you won't get convergence in distribution.

However, to "use" the CLT to argue that some sum or average should be approximately normal* -- you don't need to standardize, since if the standardized version is approximately normal, so is the unstandardized version.

---

* how this is to work** without knowing some pretty particular things about the distribution is unclear. The sense in which the distribution of some mean (say) at finite $n$ and a normal distribution are close*** is not necessarily particularly helpful for every possible purpose (e.g. knowing that two cdfs are 'within' epsilon of each other at each point may not be particularly helpful if the thing you need isn't directly related to that -- distributions with very similar cdfs may have some quite distinct properties even though their cdfs are alike).

** 'work' in the sense of being confident that the approximation will lead to sufficient accuracy for your purposes in some particular calculation

*** the value of this closeness at finite $n$ for a particular parent distribution isn't actually given by the CLT either. [The Berry-Esseen inequality does given a bound on the difference in cdf in terms of a scaled absolute third moment, $E(|X-\mu|^3)/\sigma^3$ and the square root of the sample size. No doubt other kinds of bounds should be possible, though offhand I can't name any.]